# How to make 'git not ignore' certain file extension in nested folder structure?

Tags: git

Say I have a folder structure like this:

```
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c.xml
│   │   └── d.c
│   ├── v
│       ├── e.class
│       └── g.c
|
├── m
│   ├── p
│   │   ├── w.out
│   │   └── x.c
│   ├── q
│   │   ├── y.mp3
│   │   └── z.c
```

And I only want to not ignore `*.c`.

I tried

```
*                                                                         
!*.c
```

in `.gitignore`, but that seems only work in the current level.

What I want is to set something like `!*/*/*.c`, since there may be other directories added to the git repo later, I can't hard-code the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `!*/` to your `.gitignore` to allow directories:

```
*
!*/
!*.c
```

From [gitignore man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (emphasis mine):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.** Git doesn't list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

That's why you have to exclude the directories.

Answer (score 2):

From `GITIGNORE(5)`:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

So what is happening here is that `/example.c` becomes unignored, but `/a/b/d.c` is still ignored because `/a` and `/a/b` are ignored.

The solution is to unignore all directories by putting this in your `.gitignore`:

```
*
!*/
!*.c
```